# Storage Device being Detected as Printer

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, hardware-detection

I have an HP USB thumbdrive. It was working fine but after a bad eject, it stopped. Now, when I insert it, it gets detected as a printer (from what I can tell).

My `syslog` shows this when I insert the USB in.

```
Dec 15 09:10:44 namviper kernel: [  797.472422] usb 3-3: new high-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
Dec 15 09:10:44 namviper kernel: [  797.614558] usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=03f0, idProduct=5a07
Dec 15 09:10:44 namviper kernel: [  797.614562] usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Dec 15 09:10:44 namviper kernel: [  797.614565] usb 3-3: Product: v220w
Dec 15 09:10:44 namviper kernel: [  797.614566] usb 3-3: Manufacturer: HP
Dec 15 09:10:44 namviper kernel: [  797.614568] usb 3-3: SerialNumber: 0426400000006660
Dec 15 09:10:44 namviper kernel: [  797.615308] usb-storage 3-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Dec 15 09:10:44 namviper kernel: [  797.615599] scsi host6: usb-storage 3-3:1.0
Dec 15 09:10:44 namviper root: loading HP Device 003 010
Dec 15 09:10:45 namviper python3: io/hpmud/musb.c 2183: [3413] hpmud_make_usb_uri() bus=003 dev=010
Dec 15 09:10:45 namviper python3: io/hpmud/musb.c 2281: hpmud_make_usb_uri() uri=hp:/usb/v220w?serial=SMART_INSTALL_ENABLED bytes_read=42
Dec 15 09:10:45 namviper /hp-config_usb_printer: hp-config_usb_printer[3413]: error: This is not a valid device
Dec 15 09:10:45 namviper colord[1002]: (colord:1002): Cd-WARNING **: CdMain: failed to emit DeviceAdded: failed to register object: An object is already exported for the interface org.freedesktop.ColorManager.Device at /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/sysfs_HP_v220w
```

`lsblk` does not show the device and Internet search on the error just shows printer installation debugging info.

I think I need to tell my system to treat this as a storage device but I'm not sure how.

Here's my `uname -a`:

```
Linux namviper 4.10.0-42-generic #46~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 4 15:57:59 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

---

Update: according to KamilMaciorowski's answer, the right driver is already detected:

```
$> cd "/sys/bus/usb/devices/3-3:1.0/"
$> readlink ./driver
../../../../../../bus/usb/drivers/usb-storage
```

Now I need to know what to do with this info.

Answer (score 3):

Note (edit): It turned out my original answer (below) doesn't solve the OP's problem, it only narrows it down. Having struggled whether to delete the answer or not, I'm letting it stay for educational purposes.

---

Your USB seems to report `5a07` instead of `5307`(?). Compare [usb.ids](http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids). `5a07` isn't there but maybe some printer driver matches this somehow. The mechanism is described in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29879/108618) (which seems overly pessimistic in subject of manually attaching a driver).

I don't know what exactly happened. Actually `usb-storage 3-3:1.0` from your `syslog` makes me suspect that `usb-storage` (which is the right module for a thumbdrive) was loaded, then `hpmud`(?) kicked in; I'm not sure.

But let's *assume*:

- the wrongly reported `idProduct` is the only problem (i.e. in every other aspect your USB drive works fine),
- there is indeed some wrong driver attached
- and all you need is detaching it and attaching the right one.

See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8459014), it points to [this LWN article](https://lwn.net/Articles/143397/) and it looks like a good lead (there's also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/442867) pointing to [this article](https://lwn.net/Articles/160944/)). The generic example is:

> In order to unbind a device from a driver, simply write the bus id of the device to the unbind file:
>
> ```
> echo -n "1-1:1.0" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind
> ```
>
> […]
>
> To bind a device to a driver, the device must first not be controlled by any other driver.
>
> […]
>
> Then, simply write the bus id of the device you wish to bind, into the bind file for that driver:
>
> ```
> echo -n "1-1:1.0" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb-storage/bind
> ```

In your case the bus id is `3-3:1.0`. Note it depends on USB port you used, so it will be different if you insert the thumbdrive into another socket. In a moment we will need root access and because of redirections (`>`) it's easier to start a separate shell (`sudo -s`).

At first check the currently attached driver:

```
cd "/sys/bus/usb/devices/3-3:1.0/"
readlink ./driver
```

If you're right, it will be something else than `usb-storage`.

Detach the driver, whatever it is:

```
echo -n "3-3:1.0" > ./driver/unbind
```

Load the right driver in case it's not loaded yet:

```
modprobe usb-storage
```

Attach it to the device:

```
echo -n "3-3:1.0" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb-storage/bind
```

And confirm:

```
readlink ./driver
lsblk
```

Don't forget to `exit` the root shell.

The solution is not permanent. For now I don't know how to tell Linux to always load the desired driver (I could write a script to automate the above, but it doesn't feel like the right way). Nevertheless, the thumbdrive presumably changed its `idProduct` after a bad eject, so I wouldn't trust it in a long run. Once it worked with forced `usb-storage` driver, I would run `ddrescue` to secure all data from it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed comment. I'm stumped on the first step though. `readlink ./driver` returns `../../../../../../bus/usb/drivers/usb-storage
`

Comment: @recluze This means the right driver is already there, I think. Please edit your question to indicate this fact. My answer doesn't apply and I will probably delete it.

Comment: Sure but please don't delete your answer. (Maybe just comment on the top.) It helped me learn a lot about the issue.