# Can I mount /dev/usb/hiddevX as storage type?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, usb, udev, usb-hid

I got an external HDD from a tv service provider which their receiver can access via eSATA + USB (y cable).
When plugging the device into my computer, I get:

This is dmesg:

```
[290079.510263] usb 1-1.4: new low-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[290079.624653] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=0bf0, idProduct=c010
[290079.624657] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[290079.624659] usb 1-1.4: Product: EHD100SD
[290079.624661] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: Pace
[290079.624664] usb 1-1.4: SerialNumber: 00000000000000
[290079.630804] hid-generic 0003:0BF0:C010.0008: hiddev2,hidraw6: USB HID v1.11 Device [Pace EHD100SD] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.4/input0
```

udevadm:

```
$ udevadm info --query=all -n /dev/usb/hiddev2
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/usbmisc/hiddev2
N: usb/hiddev2
E: DEVNAME=/dev/usb/hiddev2
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/usbmisc/hiddev2
E: MAJOR=180
E: MINOR=2
E: SUBSYSTEM=usbmisc
```

this is even more udevadm info:

```
$ udevadm info -a -p /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/usbmisc/hiddev2

  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/usbmisc/hiddev2':
    KERNEL=="hiddev2"
    SUBSYSTEM=="usbmisc"
    DRIVER==""
```

this is usb info:

```
$ lsusb -v -d 0bf0:c010

Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bf0:c010 Pace Micro Technology PLC 
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x0bf0 Pace Micro Technology PLC
  idProduct          0xc010 
  bcdDevice            0.00
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 3 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           41
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          4 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 No Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 None
      iInterface              4 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      51
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval              10
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval              10
```

cat of  that device reveals nothing.

Any idea how I can access the data on it without removing that seal and putting the inner hdd into my computer? There must be a filesystem somewhere.
I might not be able to read any data, but I want to see at least a `device` or a LUKS partition or anything like it of some kind…

Comment: Are you connecting USB *and* eSATA? or sole USB? It's possible eSATA is for data, USB is for power and some additional communication maybe (few special buttons?). If so, sole USB may not transfer storage data at all. But if you believe this HID device is just a smoke screen and you want to attach another driver, then see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1277343/432690).

Comment: No, because it's a char device, and not a block device. Read https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.24/source/Documentation/usb/hiddev.txt

Comment: Guess: The device uses eSATA to access the harddisk, and USB for power and for additional functions (like button(s), LED(s), ...). Connect it via eSATA and see what happens.

Comment: I connected both. The dmesg output is everything since I connected both. No block device showing up. I guess it only becomes visible once you send some password in.

Comment: @sawdust I read that. I think they are hiding the actual eSATA device somehow. Either as HID (wrong identification) or you need to send some code to activate it.

Comment: @kamil yes i connected both. I'll try to see if it mounts as usb storage. But then, why works there also be a physical eSATA connection?

Comment: Please edit question with output of `dmesg` after you plug in eSATA. *Something* must appear there if it detects a valid connection. Otherwise, check cables etc.

Comment: Hi @dirkt, there is no further output and any output about eSATA connections. This is everything I got. That's why I suspect that you might need to send some magic code to the device to activate the eSATA port.

Comment: Then this looks indeed very much like the eSATA controller is powered down in the device, and needs to be powered up somehow. You can look at the HID descriptor (google, the kernel exposes it via debugfs), but if the creators have taken pains to make it inaccessible, I very much doubt they'll tell us in the HID descriptor how to enable it. Which leaves reverse engineering, for which you need USB sniffing equipment for the USB connection between their receiver and the HDD. Which you probably don't have. I'd also suspect the contents of the HDD to be encrypted...

Answer (score 1):

HID is a user interface device. That means a lot more than keyboards and mice. Quite a few devices present a HID interface for their buttons. Others misuse it for other internal trickery and magic. Your device is also reporting as 'low speed'.

The Pace unit in question usually contains a Toshiba SATA device so you should be able to access it via the eSATA port.

Comment: This is why i posted dmesg output. It does not show as /dev/s[dg][a-z] device.